# Why MySQL 8 throws syntax error on subselect parenthesis?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I upgraded our server from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 and a query that was working now throws a syntax error. The query is more complex but simplified is like this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM ((SELECT col1 FROM tbl) AS alias)
```

The same without the exterior parenthesis works:

```
SELECT col1
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM tbl) AS alias
```

The query is auto-generated by Codeigniter query builder so it's not up to me to remove the parenthesis. Is there a directive/option in MySQL 8 to disable this syntax error?

The query builder code is like this:

```
$this->db->from("(SELECT col1 FROM tbl) AS alias");
```

Comment: Did you check that your version of Codeigniter and MySQL 8 were compatable before doing the upgrade?

Comment: Might be useful also to see your query builder code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated the question with the qb code: $this->db->from("(SELECT col1 FROM table) AS alias");

Comment: Try `$this->db->from("SELECT col1 FROM table AS alias");`

Comment: It generates `SELECT col1 FROM (SELECT col1 FROM TABLE AS alias)` , so it doesn't generate an alias for the subselect

Comment: Maybe it can be solved by the query builder but... do you think it's the expected that MySQL 8 doesn't accept this queries?

Comment: Well it seems obvious that it does not, as it is giving you an error

Comment: Table is a reserved word - is that really the name of your table or have you provided a dodgy example for the question.

Comment: It's only for the example, it's not the real table name

Comment: I don't know if anyone's still reading this but I solved a similar problem by turning my subquery into a view - ie `create view myviewname as SELECT col1 FROM tbl` then using the newly created view in place of the subquery

Comment: same problem with me, with codeigniter 2, try to upgrade your codeigniter to version 3 or above, or you can try with raw query

Comment: Hi @Dimas , have you ever found a solution? We have the same problem, we have been using Codeigniter 3 and recently migrated to MySQL 8 and a lot of queries are failing now due to extra paranthesis around table name and alias. We use query builder all over the app and cannot simply modify the code to use raw queries. Is there anything we could do, without hacking the core Codeigniter classes?

Comment: We stayed with MySQL 5.7 at the moment and we'll try with MariaDB in a next future. If you find some workaround tell me please.